# Valid Shell Script dosen't run in WSL

Tags: linux, bash, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a simple shell script which runs completly fine on VM but gives me syntex error in WSL.

```
insert(){
    read -p "Enter Name: " name
    read -p "Enter Phone Number: " phoneNumber
    echo "$name $phoneNumber" >> data.txt

}
id=100
while [ True ]
do
echo -e "[1] Insert data.\n[2] Search.\n[3]Remove Data.\n[q] Quit."
read -p "Enter yout Choice: " choice
if [ $choice -eq "4" ]; then
    break

elif [ $choice -eq "1" ];then
    insert
elif [ $choice -eq "2" ];then

    echo "Search"
elif [ $choice -eq "3" ];then

    echo "Remove"
else

    echo "Please enter proper input."
fi
done
```

Output in WSL

```
Enter Name: Poojan
: bad variable nameme
Enter Phone Number: 23212
: bad variable nameoneNumber
: not found
: not found}
try.sh: 15: Syntax error: "elif" unexpected (expecting "then")
```

Output in VM

```
[1] Insert data.
[2] Search.
[3]Remove Data.
[q] Quit.
Enter yout Choice: 1
Enter Name: Poojan
Enter Phone Number: 3423423
```

Comment: I guess it's related to the line endings

Comment: shebang ? try inserting `#!/bin/bash` as first line. (not sure about line ending in WSL)

Comment: `dos2unix your_script.sh` and then try again.

Comment: Thanks Cyrus it worked. Still I am quite curious if there is any one time fix :)

Comment: @PoojanSolanki It's likely that however you transferred it from the VM to Windows converted the line endings to DOS/Windows style, which causes lots of problems with unix tools. There's lots of info about this problem in the stackoverflow question ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)